# Can i travel alone within the eu with my article 10 family permit from italy?

Tags: uk, schengen, europe, italy, family

[image]
I would like to go on holidays without my eu family member, i use to travel alone with my residence card from italy  but am not sure of this particular permit(article 10)

Answer (score 2):

Without your EU family member, you can normally use that card (in combination with your passport) to go anywhere a Schengen residence permit will take you.  That includes the Schengen area and all but two of the non-Schengen EU countries.  The two countries that are not included are the UK and Ireland.

However, in a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139686/can-i-travel-alone-within-the-eu-with-my-article-10-family-permit-from-italy/139688?noredirect=1#comment346188_139688) you have indicated that you do not reside in Italy.  Therefore, the Italian residence card is probably no longer valid, and you should not rely on it for travel to the Schengen area or for any other purpose.  Instead, you should apply for a Schengen visa.  Because you will be traveling without your family member, you will have to pay the fee and go through the normal application procedure.

(Your UK residence card is probably a "residence card of a family member of a union citizen," in which case you could use it to travel to other EU and countries without a visa as long as you are traveling with or joining your family member there, but that is not the case here.)

Comment: @BellaVeronika if you reside in the UK then your Italian *carta di soggiorno* is probably no longer valid.  I would not try to use it if I were you.

Comment: @BellaVeronika you don't live in Italy.  The permit is probably void.

Comment: @BellaVeronika in general, you will lose your right of permanent residence in Italy after two years of absence.  At that point, the document becomes invalid because the conditions under which it was granted no longer prevail, even if the document itself has not expired.  If you have lived in the UK for less than two years then maybe you can use it.  But you should not be surprised if you are questioned at the border or at check-in for your flight.

Comment: Haha ok, im in the uk for only 2months .. does that mean i can tour the schegen or need a visa

Comment: @BellaVeronika As alluded in the previous comment, I suppose you can probably get away without a visa since you've been away from Italy for less than 2 years.  But having a UK residence card *and* an Italian one at the same time is a bit odd, and there's no guarantee it won't cause problems.  You can avoid those problems by getting a visa.

Answer (score -2):

No, you must have a visa issued based on your own rights.

In most cases a multiple entry visa is issued once for the lifetime of a passport.

---

With an Article 10 or 20 Residence Card you can

- travel **with** or **join** the EU-Spouse

to the countries in the Schengen Area.

To travel **without** the EU-Spouse or to be **joined later** by your EU-Spouse

- you must apply for a Schengen Visa

for visits to other countries in the Schengen Area.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  An article ten card issued by a Schengen country is a "residence permit" as that term is used in the Schengen Borders Code.  It therefore allows the bearer to travel to other Schengen countries without a visa, subject to the 90/180 rule, when traveling independently from the EU/EEA/Swiss family member.  (When traveling with that family member, Directive 2004/38/EC applies, and the 90/180 rule does not.)  Furthermore, Schengen visas are limited to 5 years' validity, so "once for the lifetime of a passport" is also incorrect.